# Copy query feature layer into a feature class - error 000732

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer, error-000732, query-layer, error-000725

I am trying to create a python script to copy data from a MSSQL view (includes a geometry field) into a feature class.
They are both held within the same database.

I have tried **arcpy.CopyFeatures_management** and get the following error:

> *ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset \Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.dbo.AF_VW_CCTVwastewater does not exist or is not supported
>   WARNING 000725: Output Feature Class: Dataset \Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.sde\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV_Polyline_Copy already exists.
>   Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).*

I have tried **arcpy.Append_management** and get the following error:

> *ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000732: Target Dataset: Dataset polyline does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (Append).*

I have tried **arcpy.CopyRows_management** and get the following error:

---

> *ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Input Rows: Dataset
>   \Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.dbo.AF_VW_CCTVwastewater
>   does not exist or is not supported WARNING 000725: Output Table:
>   Dataset
>   \Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.sde\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV_Polyline_Copy
>   already exists. Failed to execute (CopyRows).*

---

This is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

source_path = r'\\Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.dbo.'
output_path = r'\\Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.sde\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV\TaupoGISTest.DBO.'

polyline = output_path+r'CCTV_Polyline_Copy'

views = [r'AF_VW_CCTVwastewater', r'AF_VW_CCTVstormwater']

for view in views:
    print 'processing ' + view + '             o   o'
    print 'deleting                                      >  '
    #arcpy.TruncateTable_management(polyline)
    print 'copying                                    \_____/'
    #arcpy.CopyRows_management(source_path+view, polyline)
    #arcpy.Append_management("source_path+view", "polyline", "TEST")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(source_path+view, polyline)
```

Are there another alternative that will turn this query layer into a feature class and bypass this error?

Comment: please [edit] your Question and include a snippet of your code that isn't working

Comment: arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True will help (possibly) with your feature class already existing. What database is it? it looks like SDE but with a UNC path with only one slash '\', is that path truly valid? Are you sure you're escaping your strings properly?

Comment: Hi @MichaelMiles-Stimson I've just added in my script.  You will see that the overwrite function is already part of the script and that  my paths have two slashes - yet why does the error message only show one??

Comment: @Midavalo I have added my code.

Comment: Those paths are **not** valid -- they cannot end in a dot.  A proper path is relative to the **connection file** (`r'\windows\path\to\conn.sde\owner.tablesname'`)  The mixed case in names may also be a critical stumbling block.  Look at the examples in the documentation.

Comment: @Vince if you look at the code you will see that the path file is made up of source_path AND view so it does not end with a dot.

Comment: They're still invalid without a connection file, which is what the error states.

Comment: @Vince can you please add a link to the documentation you are referring to.

Comment: It's pretty much every ArcPy request that accepts an enterprise feature class, so no, I'm not going to provide links.  If you use a print statement, you'll see your parameters to CopyFeautres are `\\Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.dbo.AF_VW_CCTVwastewater` and `\Virgis01\gis\Naomi-AssetFindaTest\TaupoGISTest.sde\TaupoGISTest.DBO.CCTV\TaupoGISTest.DBO.AF_VW_CCTVwastewater`, neither of which is syntactically correct (the former doesn't have a connection file, the latter  has too many elements (feature datasets don't have databases)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the above comments, this has helped me with a solution.
The problem was in the source paths but there was also problems with overwriting.